# How to prove a product of k consecutive integers is always a multiple of k?

Tags: products

How to explain and prove that a product of **k** consecutive integers is always a multiple of **k**!.

Comment: For any number $k$, how often do multiples of $k$ appear when you look at the sequence of integers?

Comment: Do you know [Euclid's division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)?

Comment: Every $k$th integer is a multiple of $k$. Therefore, one of your $k$ consecutive integers is a multiple of $k$, and so is their product. A more interesting question would be, how to prove that a product of $k$ consecutive integers is divisible by $k!$.

Comment: Hi @Eldiana. Welcome! Please share your thoughts so far, so that we may answer your question at a level appropriate to you :)

Comment: sorry guys. there's a mistake in the question. was supposed to be k!.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(n+1)(n+2) \dots (n+k) = k!$
$\left( \begin{array}{c} n+k \\ n \end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For each $n$ there are $k-1$ numbers $m$ with: $nk<m<(n+1)k$.